# Querying required training courses with this example SQL schema

Tags: mysql

Given the following schema:

```
users (id, name)
courses (id, title)
training_group (id, title)
training_group_courses (training_group_id, course_id)
users_courses (user_id, course_id)
users_training_groups (user_id, training_group_id)
```

User has many courses (individually assigned)

User has many courses through training_groups, which have many courses

I want to retrieve a set of **course titles** for a particular user id that includes inidividually assigned courses (from users_courses) as well as through the users training groups relation (users_training_groups)

I can do this by running multiple queries and assembling results in a programming language, but I haven't been able to come up with a single SQL query that can do the same.

Comment: you should also add a valid data sample and the expected  .result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use two different queries and join the result using the **union** operator:

```
select c.title, 'individual' as source from users u 
join users_courses uc on u.id = uc.user_id
join courses c on c.id = uc.course_id
where u.id = 1

union all

select c.title, 'group' as source from users u 
join users_training_groups ugt on ugt.user_id = u.id
join training_group tg on ugt.training_group_id = tg.id
join training_group_courses tgc on ugt.training_group_id = tgc.training_group_id
join courses c on c.id = tgc.course_id
where u.id = 1
```